# how to convert this into cnf $(P\vee Q) \leftrightarrow (P\wedge Q)$?

Tags: logic

Given the statement $(P\vee Q) \leftrightarrow (P\wedge Q)$

How can we simplify the double implication to obtain a CNF ?
Is there any logical equivalence which I can use?

Comment: First of all : "unpack" $↔$; see [Logical equivalences involving biconditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

Answer (score 0):

**To begin:** $A\leftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to $(A\vee \neg B)\wedge(\neg A\vee B)$

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic) replacing $P \leftrightarrow Q$ with $(P \lor \lnot Q) \land (\lnot P \lor Q)$